# connect to docker app from remote server

Tags: docker, centos7

am having a confussion (I think) regarding how to manage ports and TCP connections in docker. Currently I have a server A that is running some dockers containers, I am more interested in a application that s running in the port 4444, when I type `docker container ls` I get:

```
4d2c0db7e23c        oryd/hydra:latest   "/bin/sh"                27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9010->4445/tcp   determined_snyder
7c586393ef61        oryd/hydra:latest   "/bin/sh -c '/go/b..."   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->4444/tcp             someContainer
```

So, **1)** I dont know how it's read `4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9010->4445/tcp` what it means?

Then,I have a Server B with others apps (not docker) that are trying to connect to the container that is listening in the port 4444, but I get:

```
connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

**2)** it's really the app running in the port 4444? that's why am interested in how to read the point 1

I must say that I typed in the server A this: `sudo lsof -i -P -n` and the only registers related with docker show this:

```
docker-pr 15057 root    4u  IPv6 486152035      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 15224 root    4u  IPv6 486156778      0t0  TCP *:9010 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, 1) I dont know how it's read 4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9010->4445/tcp what
>   it means?

This means that port 4445 from the container will be available as port 9010 on the host server from any interface.

To access your container from Server B, you should use the following: *hostname-of-container-host*:9010

If you want the service to be available from port 4445 of the host, you need to use -p 4445:*port-of-the-service-from-the-container*